# How to assign an instance as an attribute to another object

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am currently learning Django.  Assume a simple situation :Two tables in the database : Region->Country (1-many relationship,and Region is the foreign key of Country)

so when we are creating a new country,we have to specify the region for a country,but seems the region must be an object instead of simply names(string).

How am I going to change my html code??

```
        <div class="field">
            {{ form.region.errors }}
            <label for="id_region">Region:</label>
            <select id="id_region" name="region">
                <option value="asia">Asia</option>
                <option value="europe">Europe</option>
            </select>
            {{ form.region }}
        </div>
```

I think I should make some changes in the selection, but am I supposed to create objects here? Really confused and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add regions to the `Region` model first, then use those values while adding a `Country`. I hope you have both the models. It's not clear from your question.

Comment: you mean add region instances to the Region class and then assign them to the Country when creating country objects?yea,I understand.

Comment: The html code above is meant for user to select a region for a country, but I don't understand how to assign the region to a country, from the html code perspective.

Comment: You can add a dropdown for regions in the form for adding country.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing at all to do with your HTML code: it is all to do with how you process the form in the view.

You clearly have a Django form: that form will *already* construct and output the option values for the region field. Hard-coding them is pointless.